# RestSharp Core gzip not working

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, gzip, restsharp

I'm developing rest api client using **RestSharp.NetCore** 105.2.3 on .net core 1.1. 
When i send request (POST, GET), response from server is **not encoded** with gzip. 
When i do the same thing with **RestSharp** 105.2.3 on .net 4.5.2 (not core), it works correctly and response is **encoded** with gzip.

Cource code identical on both frameworks

```
internal class Program
    {
        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //my test Api supports gzip
            var target = "http://10.100.0.92:62872/api/TestZipPost";
            var client = new RestClient(target);
            var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
            var response = new RestResponse();

            Task.Run(async () => { response = await GetResponseContentAsync(client, request) as RestResponse; }).Wait();

            //write response "AAAAAAAAA"
            Console.WriteLine(response.Content);
        }

        public static Task<IRestResponse> GetResponseContentAsync(RestClient theClient, RestRequest theRequest)
        {
            var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<IRestResponse>();
            theClient.ExecuteAsync(theRequest, response => { tcs.SetResult(response); });
            return tcs.Task;
        }
    }
```

Request headers on Core:

> POST /api/TestZipPost HTTP/1.1 Accept: application/json,
>   application/xml, text/json, text/x-json, text/javascript, text/xml
>   Connection: Keep-Alive Content-Length: 0 Host: 10.100.0.92:62872

Request headers on .net 4.5.2

> POST /api/TestZipPost HTTP/1.1 Accept: application/json,
>   application/xml, text/json, text/x-json, text/javascript, text/xml
>   User-Agent: RestSharp/105.2.3.0 Host: 10.100.0.92:62872
>   Content-Length: 0 Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate Connection:
>   Keep-Alive

Is it a bug or i do something wrong? How can i achieve gzip encoding with RestSharop.NetCore?

Comment: And **what exactly** is your **question**? You just described an issue you are having, but no question. If it was an attempt to report a bug, I'd suggest you use more official ways and [post an issue on GitHub](https://github.com/restsharp/RestSharp/issues)

Comment: u r right, i've edit post, sry

Answer (score 0):

Install the proper RestSharp package, which supports .NET Standard, and it will work. `RestSharp.Core` is not our package.

Should you get any issues with the latest version of RestSharp - please open a GitHub issue.

Comment: does RestSharp supports .net Core 1.1?

Comment: No, only .NET Core 2.X